# ember application template don't work

Tags: ember.js

I am using ember and link this files to my index.html file and run it in my 
browser.but don't work!Please read my code and say that the problem is by
 ember code or my browser.Thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Emberjs Test</title>
    <!-- CDN's-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.1/handlebars.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/1.10.0/ember.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.10.0-beta.3/ember-template-compiler.js"></script>
    <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/release/ember.debug.js"></script>
    <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/beta/ember-data.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
        <p></p>
        <div class="navbar">
        </div>
        <div class="container" style="background-color:Yellow;height:100px;text-align:center;padding:auto;">
          <h3>Title Of Application By Ember.JS</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="container" style="background-color:pink">
           {{outlet}}
        </div>
        <footer class="container" style="background-color:black;height:100px;"></footer>

    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
      <h1>Hello to everyone and Number That Be Sohown {{number}} </h1>

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var App=Ember.Application.create();
      App.IndexController=Ember.Controller.extend({
        number:10
      });
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in console?

Comment: Did't run! I think it's by javascript! @DanielKmak

Comment: Which version of Ember do you want to use? Latest or 1.10?

Comment: Don't work on your browser too?? @DanielKmak

Comment: This error! `Uncaught TypeError: Application.instanceInitializer is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change contents of your `<head>` tag:

```
<head>
    <title>Emberjs Test</title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.13.5/ember-template-compiler.js"></script>
    <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.13.5/ember.debug.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
```

Comment: My browser is just loading! @DanielKmak

Comment: Thanks my freind it worked! but i want to know what???I download this files and put on my local folder and include But not worked! but in your answer it's worked @Danielkmak

Comment: Make sure to download files exactly as they are in these 4 files in my answer. Then make sure you didn't mistype any URL to those files and it should work.

Comment: Thanks!again @DanielKmak

Comment: No problem. Good luck.